# I am trying to filter on car brands and fuel, for my car website. But it does not filter results. Can anyone help me?

Tags: php, pdo, where-in

I am trying to filter some records with AJAX and PHP prepared statements. At the moment the query does not give back any results. I think it is because the query itself, but I am not sure.  Is the error occurring because of the values that are passed through? Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
    if(isset($_POST['action']))
    {
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM occasions WHERE naam IS NOT NULL";
        
        if(isset($_POST['merk'])){
            $sql .= " AND merk IN(:merk)";
            
            $merk = implode(",", $_POST['merk']);
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST['brandstof'])){
            $sql .= " AND brandstof IN(:brandstof)";
            
            $brandstof = implode(",", $_POST['brandstof']);
        }
```

The problem here is: the query filters one time, when a second $merk value has been inputted, it won't filter. Why is that? Same with $brandstof.

```
        //We prepare our SELECT statement.
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        
        
        
        
        if(isset($_POST['merk'])){
            $statement->bindParam(':merk', $merk);
        }

        if(isset($_POST['brandstof'])){
            $statement->bindParam(':brandstof', $brandstof);
        }
```

Are these parameters bound correctly?

```
        //Execute statement.
        $statement->execute();
        
        print_r($statement);

        //Fetch the result.
        $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $output = "";
        
        if(count($results) > 0)
        {
            foreach($results as $occasion)
            {
                $output .= 
                    '<a href="../show/"'.$occasion['id'].'" " style="width: 33%; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="width:300px; display:inline-block;">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="occasion-img">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="/uploads/'.$occasion['foto'].'" alt=""'.$occasion['naam'].'"" title=""'.$occasion['naam'].'"" style="width:100%; height:270px; object-fit:cover;">
                                </div>

                                <div class="occasion-tekst" style="padding:10px 10px;">
                                    <h2>'.$occasion['naam'].'</h2>
                                    <p style="line-height:1.0;">
                                        <?php echo $beschrijving; ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <h4 style="text-align:center;">
                                        &#8364; '.number_format($occasion['prijs'],2,",","").'
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $output = "<h3>Er zijn geen producten gevonden</h3>" . $merk;
        }
        echo $output;
        echo $sql;
    }
```

If results are found, then it will output as HTML.

Comment: Why do you implode it? It will be a string after imploding, and not a list of values.

Comment: Should it be a list of values to make the IN() clause work? Or can it also work with string values?

Comment: If you bind a single string then it will match only against that single value. You need to bind a list of items. MySQL doesn't explode the string into separate values. See the linked post.